# Will I get Windows 10 without reserving if I have genuine Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

I have genuine Windows 7. I have the latest update and the 2 updates required for reserving windows 10 but I am not getting the notification icon to reserve the windows 10. I tried all the 3 methods from the batch file. Nothing happened. I tried running GWX.exe manually with administrator privilege but nothing happened. What should I do? Will I be able to upgrade to Windows 10 when it releases?

Comment: @Raystafarian No, it is not duplicate. Read the question and details.

Comment: Take a look through the **recent** questions for your [tag](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-upgrade) and see how it all leads back to the same duplicate.

Comment: @Raystafarian But my question is completely different.

Comment: I'm not sure why @Raystafarian thinks the question he marked is a duplicate exactly, but hey.  Regardless, the one I marked is.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 But that question doesn't solve my problem. I have already seen that question that is why I asked.

Comment: That doesn't make it a different question. If you'd like more/updated answers to the existing one, please consider [placing a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on it.  If you really feel your question is worth being separate, then include (in your question) a reference to the other question, exactly what you tried already, and what the results were.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Now I am doing it from mobile. Will add complete details tomorrow. Hope it doesn't get deleted.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I got lost in a maze of duplicates of duplicates, whoops (Also - *nice* gold badge. Pankaj - sorry I didn't pick a question that made more sense as being a duplicate - apologies.